# Why won't my CSS work on GitHub Pages?

Tags: css, github, github-pages

I'm making a web game called Sweet Shoppe, and I'm using GitHub Pages with it. The only problem is, the CSS won't work on GitHub Pages.

I've tried putting the CSS file in the main repo (and in a folder) and importing it through the HTML, but when I go to my page URL (which is set to mreikono.github.io/Sweet-Shoppe) the CSS that I have in the file (which adds a background of gray stripes to the body) fails to show up.

Mainly I want to know the following: What is the correct way to import some CSS into GitHub Pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like bootstrap is overriding your background color on line 896.

```
body {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555555;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Try loading your stylesheet after bootstrap so that your styles are prioritized.

```
<head>
    <!-- Extra code files -->

    <!-- External files -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://bootswatch.com/lumen/bootstrap.css">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.js"></script>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Misc attributes -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sweet Shoppe</title>
</head>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade

Comment: I suppose background-color can't override background-image, can it?

Comment: This is correct. If you load the inspector, you will see that Bootstrap's background-color is overriding the background-image.

Comment: @RomanGotsiy - It does not. But the image is white and you can only see it over his background color.

Comment: OK, sry. My browser hasn't loaded bootstap.css (because of security reasons: page over https and css over http - i have never seen such behavior o_O :), so it worked for me...