# Why won't my JavaScript work on GitHub Pages?

Tags: javascript, github, github-pages

After the events of [this question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24792958/why-wont-my-css-work-on-github-pages), where my CSS wasn't working on GitHub, I created a JavaScript file, and now that file isn't working.

I have a button in the HTML, and when you click it, your unit of currency (right now: cookies; remember that this game is Sweet Shoppe) is supposed to go up, but nothing's happening when I click it.

Here's the [link to the repo](http://github.com/MrEikono/Sweet-Shoppe) one more time. Can someone look at the JS file and see what's going wrong this time?

Thanks.

Comment: If you can't present a **self-contained** question, then this isn't appropriate for SO. There's no guarantee that this question will make any sense in 6 months time because the out-links may change or break.

Comment: also, do you specifically have problems with your CSS not working on the github _repo_ page _or_ a github.io page?

Comment: @ivy_lynx - I think you might have misunderstood a bit, my CSS is working now. I just put that there so it could be like "after the CSS problem, now I have another problem".

Answer (score 3):

Your [HTML markup](http://mreikono.github.io/Sweet-Shoppe/) is incorrect:

```
<link href="js/main.js" type="text/javascript">
```

should be

```
<script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```